# Pushing / uploading data from multiple Raspberry Pi to GDrive (or another cloud service)

Tags: pi-4, owncloud

I'd like to use a couple of RPIs to record photos (like one photo each 1h and a maximum of 5-10 Raspberrys). GDrive seems like a good option but I need to be able to access the Drive reliably from all devices.
It seems possible to mount a GDrive to the RPI:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=109587

But is this a solution for multiple devices or should I consider another cloud service like Amazon S3?

Comment: I just use a low cost hosting server and secure FTP / Rsync.  You could host the files yourself on one of the Pi's and create a VPN between them :-)

Comment: @Andrew how do you establisih an SFTP connection? I've tested FTP and it worked after 5min but sftp seems more complex since I need to retrieve the host keys for my provider.

Comment: best to talk with your hosting provider - if they give you ssh to your server then the first time you ssh in the remote copy should be copied to ~/.shh/known_hosts on your Pi for you. You then need to generate a key for your local machine using `ssh-keygen`, copy it to the remote machine using `ssh-copyid` and then rsync using the user@targetIP: as the destination https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-transfer-files-with-rsync-over-ssh/ has a good walkthrough.